# Python idle until I want it to change somethng

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots, gpio

I suck at python, just getting that out there.  Anyway, I'm trying to write some code to simply update a progress bar in a QTgui when a signal is received on the GPIO pins of a Razzleberry Pi.  I've searched allot, and probably looked right at the answer, but my limited understanding of python probably made me miss it.  The code that doesn't work is as follows:

```
import os
os.environ["DISPLAY"] = ":0"
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
import time
# This gets the Qt stuff
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

# This is our window from QtCreator
import mainwindow

GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
p=0
def my_callback(channel):
    global recv
    recv=0
    if (GPIO.input(19) == GPIO.HIGH):
        recv=recv+1
    if (GPIO.input(13) == GPIO.HIGH):
        recv=recv+2
    if (GPIO.input(6) == GPIO.HIGH):
        recv=recv+4
    if (GPIO.input(5) == GPIO.HIGH):
        recv=recv+8
    if (GPIO.input(21) == GPIO.HIGH):
        recv=recv+16
    if (GPIO.input(20) == GPIO.HIGH):
        recv=recv+32
    if (GPIO.input(16) == GPIO.HIGH):
        recv=recv+64
    if (GPIO.input(12) == GPIO.HIGH):
        recv=recv+128
    print (recv)
GPIO.add_event_detect(26, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300)
#import smbus
# create class for our Raspberry Pi GUI
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, mainwindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    # access variables inside of the UI's file
    def doStuff(self):
        global p
        if (recv == 255):
            self.progressBar.setValue = p
        if (recv == 135):
            self.barTemp.setValue = p
        p=p+1
        time.sleep(0.1)

    def __init__(self):
 #       GPIO.add_event_detect(26, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300)
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # gets defined in the UI file
 #       self.btnTest.clicked.connect(lambda: self.difthread(1))
        self.btnTemp.clicked.connect(lambda: self.doStuff())

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    # without this, the script exits immediately.
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

recv=0
        # a new app instance




# python bit to figure how who started This
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I hoped adding the trigger would help it smarten up, but didn't work.  I'm kinda lost with python when it comes to what goes where and why it's so selfish (bet you've never heard that before) anyway, if anyone could help I'd be eternally in your debt, and hope you don't mind my ignorance.

Edit: Just want to throw in that the callbacks and everything are working ok.  Ideally, what I want it to do is display the gui, then start looping through the "doStuff" routine over and over.  Later on I will make that routine act differently based on input recieved, but in the meantime, just trying to get it to respond at all.  The global "p" is essentially a variable that allows the program to react based on how many times it's looped through (I know p is a crappy variable name, but my variables tend to get very "sweary" when I'm frustrated, so I edited it for better human consumption)

Edit: So small update, changed the dostuff to the following:

```
def doStuff(self):
    while (1):
        global p
        if (recv == 255):
            self.progressBar.setValue(p)
        if (recv == 135):
            self.barTemp.setValue (p)
        p=p+1
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Apparently I wasn't using "setValue" correctly.  So now that this is working, how would I go about removing the requirement of the button.  ie, how can I make it work by starting the loop when a certain value is received through the GPIO's?

Edit: I may just have the wrong terminology which is hurting my ability to find the answer myself.  In this case, the "hook" is when a button is pressed.  How would I make it so the "hook" is when a variable equals something?

Comment: Just try searching python, qt and gpio (which will dump you in Graspberry land). There are infinite variants of this question and various answers (you are, of course, doing it wrong)

Comment: Yeah, searching those is kind of how I ended up in this mess in the first place, and I haven't been able to find any that use the value of a variable as a hook.  Also, thanks for letting me know I'm doing it wrong.  You informing me of that while at the same time providing no insight as to where/how I'm going wrong, really helps show me that I'm just bad at this and should just give up, while, I'm sure, helping anyone else who stumbles across this page just get frustrated and give up too.

Comment: You are most welcome. Generally, for this sort of thing to work most of your code needs to be event based, i.e. something happens, you get called, you respond to it. Both for your i/o and your GUI. If you find yourself writing infinite loops, blocking io or using `sleep`, it's probably going to work poorly, if at all.

Comment: But the intent is for it to continue looping after the initial signal is received, and continue looping after.  I just need to know how to change: self.btnTemp.clicked.connect(lambda: self.doStuff()) into, when p = 25, perform dostuff().  There is literally no need for it to be running well.  This is rapid prototyping of code only used by me and discarded when the project changes.

Comment: I'm sorry, in all honesty this is really frustrating.  I actually managed to find a number of questions similiar to mine, and the answers provided were pretty much always "what you want to do is wrong, you should do it a different way".  And then OP explains that they need to do it that way for a reason, and then no response.  I can only assume at this point that nobody on here really knows how to do it.  I've found information on using signals and slots to do this kind of thing with qt objects, what I'm struggling with is how to format it to work with something like a variable.

Comment: I don't know what answers you read but again, fundamentally, you want your program to respond to events. If you're implementing an endless loop with sleep and polling, something is not going right. If your idea is 'well, I want to do it this way anyway', fair enough but maybe you should try to understand why people are recommending other things.